# Apply nested if statement on df

Tags: python, pandas, nested-if

The following code must perform a few steps:

1. if column 'wholesale data' usage >= column 'mbs' than
2. Subtract column 'wholesale data' - 'mbs'
3. Multiply the difference based on the following table

   - 32 - 0.56
   - 64 - 0.5
   - 128 - 0.4
   - 256 - 0.4
   - 512 - 0.3
   - 1024 - 0.3
4. For all other possible option - 0

I have got the following code

```
if df['Wholesale Data Usage'] >= df['mbs']:
    if df['mbs'] == "32":
        df['Additional Charge'] = (df['Wholesale Data Usage'] - df[
        'mbs']) * 0.5
    elif df['mbs'] == "64":
        df['Additional Charge'] = (df['Wholesale Data Usage'] - df[
        'mbs']) * 0.5
    elif df['mbs'] == "128":
        df['Additional Charge'] = (df['Wholesale Data Usage'] - df[
        'mbs']) * 0.4
    elif df['mbs'] == "256":
        df['Additional Charge'] = (df['Wholesale Data Usage'] - df[
        'mbs']) * 0.4
    elif df['mbs'] == "512":
        df['Additional Charge'] = (df['Wholesale Data Usage'] - df[
        'mbs']) * 0.3
    elif df['mbs'] == "1024":
        df['Additional Charge'] = (df['Wholesale Data Usage'] - df[
        'mbs']) * 0.3
    else:
        df['Additional Charge'] = 0
else:
    df['Additional Charge'] = 0
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: The indentation is wrong at the start and the end.  You appear to have two `else` statements, but it is difficult to know with the incorrect indentation.  You might consider using a dictionary for the table, it would be much simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youve got code so hard to read its hard to debug. Coding style will help you to see your own errors I think. What if you wrote it like this?

```
mbs = df['mbs']
wdu = df['Wholesale Data Usage']

ac = 0
if wdu >= mbs and mbs == "32"   : ac = (wdu - mbs) * 0.56
if wdu >= mbs and mbs == "64"   : ac = (wdu - mbs) * 0.5
if wdu >= mbs and mbs == "128"  : ac = (wdu - mbs) * 0.4
if wdu >= mbs and mbs == "256"  : ac = (wdu - mbs) * 0.4
if wdu >= mbs and mbs == "512"  : ac = (wdu - mbs) * 0.3
if wdu >= mbs and mbs == "1024" : ac = (wdu - mbs) * 0.3

df['Additional Charge'] = ac
```

That being said you have a type problem. I the first equality `mbs=="32"` you are comparing as if you have a string. Then in the equation you try to add the values as if they contain a int -- which isn't going to work. Lets make the types consitent.

```
mbs = float(df['mbs'])
wdu = float(df['Wholesale Data Usage'])

ac = 0
if wdu >= mbs and mbs == 32   : ac = (wdu - mbs) * 0.56
if wdu >= mbs and mbs == 64   : ac = (wdu - mbs) * 0.5
if wdu >= mbs and mbs == 128  : ac = (wdu - mbs) * 0.4
if wdu >= mbs and mbs == 256  : ac = (wdu - mbs) * 0.4
if wdu >= mbs and mbs == 512  : ac = (wdu - mbs) * 0.3
if wdu >= mbs and mbs == 1024 : ac = (wdu - mbs) * 0.3

df['Additional Charge'] = str(ac) #<- you need to know what the expected type is here.
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for 32, you are multiplying by 0.5 and not 0.56.

Then, it seems that you have muddled up **Strings** and **Integers**. If the data stored in `df['Wholesale Data Usage']` and `df['mbs']` is of type String then you cannot check greater than (`>=`) nor can you subtract one from the other.

I suspect that the data stored in the dictionary is of type **Integer** or **Float** or **Double**. In which case you are trying to compare the data to strings and should change the following:

```
if df['mbs'] == "32":
```

to:

```
if df['mbs'] == 32:
```

and do the same for every comparison

Answer (score 0):

I think you've just got a few issues with your logic and the way the code would step through the logic e.g. You check if the `mbs` column is equal to 32 but really it should be if the difference between the `Wholesale Data Usage` column and the `mbs` column is equal to 32.

This should fix your logic without editing too much of your code:

```
df['mbs'] = np.where(df['Wholesale Data Usage'] >= df['mbs'], df['Wholesale Data Usage']-df['mbs'], 0)

if df['mbs'] == "32":
    df['Additional Charge'] = (df['mbs']) * 0.5
elif df['mbs'] == "64":
    df['Additional Charge'] = (df['mbs']) * 0.5
elif df['mbs'] == "128":
    df['Additional Charge'] = (df['mbs']) * 0.4
elif df['mbs'] == "256":
    df['Additional Charge'] = (df['mbs']) * 0.4
elif df['mbs'] == "512":
    df['Additional Charge'] = (df['mbs']) * 0.3
elif df['mbs'] == "1024":
    df['Additional Charge'] = (df['mbs']) * 0.3
else:
    df['Additional Charge'] = 0
```

Comment: I dont think so... It the total usage is over the limit they are charged the rate plus an additional charge for every unit over the limit. So his logic works. 
I assume `df['Total Cost']` is calced `df['Regualr Charges'] + df['additional charges'] such that he is calculating overage charges in the above. Your logic seems to give a discount for going over ?